# Solving Euler's equidimensional equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was given the following problem:

"Consider the Euler's equidimensional equation

$x^2y''(x) + pxy'(x)+qy(x) = 0$ on $(0,+\infty)$. Here $p,q\in \Bbb R$ are given constants. Show that $Y(t) = y(e^t)$ solves

$\frac{d^2}{dt^2}Y(t) + (p-1) \frac{d}{dt}Y(t) + qY(t) = 0$ on $\Bbb R$

Then, use this technique to find the general solution of the following equation on $(0, +\infty)$:

$x^2y''(x)-xy'(x)+y(x)=x$

"

For the first part, I managed to show it, but I took the Euler's equidimensional equation as an identity, which I think is incorrect. I essentially let $Y(t) := y(x(t))=y(e^t)$, and then took the derivate and second-derivate with chain rule, then plugged in and used the given "identity" to get 0. However, like I said I feel like this solution is incorrect.

For the second part, I have no idea how the first part's "technique" would help.

I have found similar problems online, but the suggested solutions involve substituting $y = x^m$, while this problem asks for another approach that I can't figure out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have followed the correct technique for the first part.  Let me describe the reasoning.

- First, write down an equation you don't know how to solve.  This is Euler's equidimensional equation in your problem.
- Second, write down another, perhaps easier equation.  Show that a solution to the first equation, $y(t)$,  can be adapted to be a solution of the second equation, $Y(t)$.  This will use the first equation as an identity to simplify the resulting expression(s) involving $y(t)$.
- Find a way to directly solve the second equation.  Here, this is a second order constant coefficient homogeneous linear ODE, so you should have no trouble doing so.
- Use your relation between the solutions of the two equations and your solution to the second equation to write down a solution to the first equation.  That is, once you can write the explicit version of $Y(t)$, you are simultaneously in possession of an explicit version of $y(\mathrm{e}^t)$, so you can find $y$ by using $Y$ and the relation $x = \mathrm{e}^t$ and/or the equivalent, $\ln x = t$.

Comment: I see... I still feel a little bit like I bumbled through my solution for the first part. Specifically, I don't quite understand how the two equations are linked. Has the second equation that is given to me specifically been formulated before-hand to give a solution to the first? For example, if I take some random 2nd order ODE to be my second equation, I assume it wouldn't be much help at all.

Comment: @punypaw : Correct.  This is actually presenting Euler's substitution for solving his equation "out of thin air" by choosing $x = \mathrm{e}^t$ and "noticing" that this substitution gives a constant coefficient new equation.  It probably seems more obvious if you are Euler and you've been noodling with the original equation for a a few days seeing what happens when you make various substitutions.
There is a "unified" way to get this, using Lie symmetries of the differential equation -- but you need some additional math (group theory et al.) before you are ready to add this to your toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

$$x^2y''(x)-xy'(x)+y(x)=x$$
Solve the homogeneous DE:
$$x^2y''(x)-xy'(x)+y(x)=0$$
With the equation
$$\frac{d^2}{dt^2}Y(t) + (p-1) \frac{d}{dt}Y(t) + qY(t) = 0$$
You have that $p=-1,q=1$ so that you need to solve:
$$\frac{d^2}{dt^2}Y(t) -2 \frac{d}{dt}Y(t) + Y(t) = 0$$
$$Y''(t) -2 Y'(t) + Y(t) = 0$$
The characteristic polynomial is just:
$$r^2-2r+1=(r-1)^2=0 \implies r=1$$
Then the solution to the homogeneous DE is:
$$Y(t)=c_1e^t+c_2te^t$$
$$\implies y(x)=c_1x+c_2x \ln x$$
Then solve the inhomogeneous DE:
$$\frac{d^2}{dt^2}Y(t) -2 \frac{d}{dt}Y(t) + Y(t) = e^t$$
Try the Method of Undetermined Coefficients. The guess should be:
$$Y_p(t)=At^2e^t$$
Plug this in the DE and find the constant $A$.
$$ \implies y_p(x)=A x \ln^2 x$$

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! May I ask, how did you obtain the values for p?

Comment: Yes of course you have to consider your differential equation on the form you are given  $x^2y''(x) + pxy'(x)+qy(x) = 0$ thats how you can deduce the value of $p$ and $q$ and apply the formula @punypaw

Comment: And the DE you try to solve is this $x^2y''(x)-xy'(x)+y(x)=0$ easy to deduce now $p$ @punypaw

Comment: Oh I see now. Thank you so much!